# How could i create a set of buttons with a loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have this program i'm trying to create, and basically i need to make 8 rows of buttons in tkinter
but i can't figure out how i could do this with a loop
, without a loop i did this :

```
def decimal():
app = Toplevel(root)
app.title("Traducteur décimal")
app.geometry("400x200")
r1 = Button(app, text="LED 1 ON")
r2 = Button(app, text="LED 1 OFF")
r1.place(x=125,y=0)
r2.place(x=225,y=0)
r3 = Button(app, text="LED 2 ON")
r4 = Button(app, text="LED 2 OFF")
r3.place(x=125, y=40)
r4.place(x=225, y=40)
r5 = Button(app, text="LED 3 ON")
r6 = Button(app, text="LED 3 OFF")
r5.place(x=125, y=80)
r6.place(x=225, y=80)
```

By the way i'm sorry for the bad English.
Thanks

Comment: by the way i know this could be possible with object oriented programming but i have very little experience with it

Comment: Use `grid()`, you will get a better answer faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is to put them all in a `list` of `2-tuples` with a `for` loop. Being a list, you can access its elments after via indexing:

```py
buttons = []

x_loc_on, x_loc_off = (125, 225)

y_start = 0
y_offset = 40

commands = [<16 functions here>]

for row in range(8):
    # calculate the pair's y-position based on row
    y_pos_of_row = y_start + row * y_offset

    # get the row number (starts from 1 unlike the variable `row`; so adding 1)
    row_number = row + 1

    # generate the ON button
    button_1 = Button(app, text=f"LED {row_number} ON", command=commands[row])
    button_1.place(x=x_loc_on, y=y_pos_of_row)

    # generate the OFF button
    button_2 = Button(app, text=f"LED {row_number} OFF", command=commands[row+1])
    button_2.place(x=x_loc_off, y=y_pos_of_row)

    # put this row's ON-OFF button pair as a 2-tuple into a list
    buttons.append((button_1, button_2))
```

Then you can access `i`th row and `ON` button via `buttons[i][0]` and same row `OFF` button via `buttons[i][1]`.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed works but how can i modify the text into it ? The buttons are only displaying LED 1 ON and LED 1 OFF

Comment: @Tahet Yes, sorry about that.. Now fixed with an `f-string`.

Comment: Im sorry it may sound stupid but how do i interact with these new buttons? I need to put command parameters in them

Comment: @Tahet No, not at all stupid but can you be more specific? Do you want one command for all of them, or one command per row, or one command for each button, or one command for ON buttons and one command for OFF buttons etc.

Comment: I want to use 1 command for each button, example : LED 1 ON would turn on the first led or LED 2 OFF would turn off the second led

Comment: @Tahet I see; then you can form a list of 16 commands for all buttons. Then since `row` is going from `0` to `7`, we can index that list with `row` and `row+1` in each turn of for loop to get the corresponding command for each button. Edited the answer.