# How can I give identical buttons created in a loop unique names in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, names

I have used a loop to create 3 blank buttons inside frames (so I can make them an exact size using dimensions instead of height and width) inside a larger frame that organizes them into a grid. These buttons all display ok but later on in the program I want to change the text individually but because they do not have unique names I cannot use config.
Here is the button creating code:

```
frameNames = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
while buttonNumber <= 11:
        frameN = frameNames[buttonNumber]
        frame = tkinter.Frame(buttonFrame, width=100, height=100)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_propagate(0)
        if "A" in frameN:
            frame.grid(row = 0)
        elif "B" in frameN:
            frame.grid(row = 1)
        elif "C" in frameN:
            frame.grid(row = 2)
        if "1" in frameN:
            frame.grid(column = 0)
        elif "2" in frameN:
            frame.grid(column = 1)
        elif "3" in frameN:
            frame.grid(column = 2)
        elif "4" in frameN:
            frame.grid(column = 3)
        frame.grid(padx = 25, pady = 25)
        button = tkinter.Button(frame, text = " ", bg = "Blue").grid(sticky="nsew")
        buttonNumber += 1
    
    window.mainloop()
```

Let me know if you need any more info
Thanks

Comment: Store them in a list or dictionary.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67032385/7432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the created buttons and use the cell position or name (from `frameNames`) as the key:

```py
frameNames = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"]
buttons = {}  # dictionary to hold the buttons
for name in frameNames:
    row = ord(name[0]) - ord("A")
    col = int(name[1]) - 1
    frame = tk.Frame(buttonFrame, width=100, height=100)
    frame.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=25, pady=25)
    btn = tk.Button(frame, bg="blue")
    btn.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    buttons[row,col] = btn  # or buttons[name] = btn
```

Then you can access a particular button using the key `row,col`, e.g. `buttons[0,0]`.

Comment: It will be a while before I get a chance to test this but this solution seems perfect. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi was just wanting to know what name I will need to use to refer to each button? Do I go A1.config, buttons{A1}.config etc.?

Comment: If you used names from `frameNames` as keys in `buttons`, then use `buttons["A1"].config(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Found this answer 2 years later and it was exactly what I needed.